# Redirect stdout and stderr to socket for a distributed shell program

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, exec

I made a distributed shell program that has a client and server. The client sends a command request to the server and the server executes that command locally and is supposed to output the results of that command to the client. I am having trouble figuring out how to redirect stdout/stderr to the client. I use execvp to execute the command.

I think I might have to use dup2? But I can't figure out how to use it properly. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to use `dup2()` to duplicate the socket's file descriptor onto the stderr and stdout file descriptors.  It's pretty much the same thing as redirecting to pipes.

```
cpid = fork();
if (cpid == 0) {
  dup2(sockfd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(sockfd, STDERR_FILENO);
  execvp(...);
  /*... etc. etc. */
```

Comment: So I tried this method but no output shows up on the client side. But in place of sockfd, I just put the variable of my socket. I'm guessing that's not the actual file descriptor of the socket? How do I actually find out what the file descriptor of the socket is?

Comment: The socket file descriptor (on the server) is the one returned by `accept()` -- the same one you'd read/write to/from if you weren't using `fork()`/`execvp()`.  If that's the one you're using, there might be a different problem with your code.

Comment: is there any code I should be doing client side in order for the output to come through? Do I need to do a read() or something of that sort [as if the server was writing something to that port]

Comment: On the client side, it shouldn't be any different from if your server generated the output itself... yes, you'll need to read it somehow (possibly with `read()`), but you'd have to do that anyway.  You might consider using a telnet program to connect to your server to test it out if you're not sure whether your client works properly yet.  Also (in the server), make sure to `wait()` or `waitpid()` for the child process in the parent process, and close the socket in the parent.

Comment: ok cool, it works now. I just didn't call read() on the client side (I wasn't sure whether redirecting the output with dup2 required a read on the client side). Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @y3di hello, I am trying to solve the same problem now.  I used `dup2(newsock, STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(newsock, STDERR_FILENO);` but it only output the first lines of output.  any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: @Dmitri could you please take a look at [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100817/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-socket-in-c)?  Thanks