# Can I redirect a parent process's stderr to a socket file descriptor on a forked process?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, stdio

I've written a daemon that during development had its debugging information going to stderr (before it was fully 'daemonized').  Now the code is more mature, so the stderr has been redirected to `/dev/null` with an `freopen(2)` call.  For the purposes of debugging, I'd really like to be able to connect to the server daemon, send a command and have it magically start sending the `stderr` stream over the socket.

**Is there a way (in a forked process) to do a '`dup(2)`' like operation on `stderr` of the *parent process* to the child's socket file descriptor?** A Linux only solution is acceptable.

There are great swaths of code that print to `stderr`, that - *for verification purposes* - I would rather simply not touch.

*If `dup2` could do what I'm asking, this would work: [Redirect STDOUT and STDERR to socket in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8100817/32836)*

Comment: Have you considered sending it to a FIFO and netcating it out?

Comment: I'm confused by the _child_ and _parent_ discussion in the question; does the server `fork(2)` a child for every client? do you want to get the _parent's_ debugging information from one of these spawned children?

Comment: @sarnold Yes & Yes.  I would like to get the parent's debugging information on *one* of the spawned children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a process has `fork(2)`ed, the child and parent processes do not share file descriptor tables, so operations in one do not influence the other. The Linux-specific `clone(2)` system call allows processes to share the file descriptor table using `CLONE_FILES` and filesystem information (filesystem root, current working directory, umask) can be shared with `CLONE_NS`. Using `clone(2)` might be too large a re-write for your purposes -- and because it is out of the ordinary, working with it might be annoying.

Another approach, one [bmargulies suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8736794/377270), is to create an "error server" portion of the parent process that tells clients which port to `connect(2)` to to read error information. If you stick with TCP, it'll work over networks but be open to all without some authentication and authorization code. If you use `unix(7)` sockets, you can use `SCM_CREDENTIALS` messages to check the user, group, and pid of the connecting process.

You could also create a new `pipe(7)` using the `pipe(2)` system call for *every* child, before `fork(2)`, and just waste the filedescriptors if the child *doesn't* want the debugging information.

If you use a `unix(7)` socket to provide parent to child communication, you could use the `SCM_RIGHTS` message to send a filedescriptor from one process to another -- you could either have the parent send a `pipe(7)` or `socket(7)` to the child for reading or have the child send the parent a `pipe(7)` or `socket(7)` for writing.

Comment: A cogent and very informative answer with tractable suggestions.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Once the parent process has forked, the child is unable to forcibly change the status of anything in the parent process.  It can conceivable communicate with the parent and request it to change where it writes its standard error output, but the child cannot force the parent to do it.  Further, if the parent closed the socket to the client after forking (which it normally would), then it cannot communicate easily with the client.

There are ways to migrate a (socket) file descriptor between processes, but I'm tolerably certain that is a cooperative process too.  If you want to go down that route, then this [page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzab6/rzab6cdescriptors.htm) has a description of what to do and links to the client-end and server-end programs to do the work.  (You need an AF_UNIX socket connection and use the `sendmsg()` in the child daemon and `recvmsg()` in the parent daemon.  With that setup, the child daemon could arrange to pass the client's socket connection to the parent daemon, and the parent daemon would then `dup2()` the file descriptor received to 2 (standard error), and would then close the original descriptor received.  Thereafter, standard error output would go to the client.

This requires care in the setup, and (as already stated) cooperation between the child and the parent daemon processes.  I've not actually done this directly myself, so I'm not sure of the pitfalls in the process.  I do know it is actually fairly widely usable, at least on Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with a `dup2`?

In the parent, `socket` and `connect` in the parent and pass the number in argv.  Pass the file descriptor of the write side of the pipe to the child in argv. Then `close(2)`, and `dup2(numberFromArgv, 2)`?

Or, just pass the port number of the error server to the child (or hardwire it), and let it call `socket`, `connect`, and `dup2`.

Come to think of it, I bet that the main problem here is the 'f' part of it. After you call freopen, the descriptor number is probably no longer '2'. Call `fileno` to obtain the number, and then use `dup2` to move the socket to that number.

Comment: I tried that (I think, the brevity of your answer is confusing).  In a child invoking `dup2(sockfd, STDERR_FILENO);` doesn't give the desired results.  This was tried on code that didn't `freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr);` in the parent process.  However, if I do a `dup2(STDOUT_FILENO,STDERR_FILENO);` in the parent I see all the debugging information on stdout which led me to think that a forked process couldn't operate on the parent's file descriptors.

Comment: I like the "error server" idea here, but that does potentially expose the error messages to other clients as well.