# Linux Socket - read returns 0 after redirecting stdout/stderr

Tags: c, linux, sockets, fork

I'm implementing logging for a game engine as an external process on my local machine via sockets. It runs as a process that invokes the engine, like a shell. The long-term plan is to have IPC between the engine and tools. My current problem is that recv() returns 0 and errno is clear after redirecting stdout / stderr Here's the code. As a test, all error checking is done with assert. Currently, no asserts trigger.

engine.c - process A

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    init_debug();

    is_running = 1;
    while(is_running) {
         // read input
         // update entities
         // render frame / present
    }
}

int init_debug(void)
{
    s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    assert(s != -1);
    
    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(remote.sun_path, "/tmp/qsw.sock");
    remote_len = SUN_LEN(&remote);
    
    s2 = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, remote_len);
    
    if(s2 == -1) {
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        assert(0);
    }
                
    assert(dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO) != -1);
    assert(dup2(s2, STDERR_FILENO) != -1);
    
    send(STDERR_FILENO, "hello, world\n", 13, 0); // should be redirected to socket 's2'
}
```

shell.c - process B

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_un addr, remote;
    socklen_t addr_len;
    int s, out_fd;
    
    s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    assert(s != -1);
    
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof addr);
    memset(&remote, 0, sizeof remote);
    
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(addr.sun_path, "/tmp/qsw.sock");
    unlink(addr.sun_path);
    
    addr_len = sizeof addr.sun_family + strlen(addr.sun_path);
    assert(bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, addr_len) != -1);

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) { // NOTE: child process
        sleep(1);
        char *cmd = "./build/release/bin/qsw";
        char *cmdline[] = { "qsw", "-x", NULL };
        execvp(cmd, cmdline);
    } else { // NOTE: parent process; no error handling
        assert(listen(s, 2) != -1);
        socklen_t remote_len = SUN_LEN(&remote);
        
        out_fd = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &remote_len);
        if(out_fd == -1) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    char buffer[16384];
    ssize_t buffer_len;
    
    int log_fd = open("log.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    
    buffer_len = recv(out_fd, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0);
    printf("%s: %lld\n", strerror(errno), (long long)buffer_len);
    write(log_fd, buffer, buffer_len);
}
```

Comment: @Jesse Lactin - .  I recall this is a bit tricky to get right.  Had to do it a few times in the past. Maybe the accepted answer here will help
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100817/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-socket-in-c

Comment: I think it's because you're not redirecting stderr/stdout BEFORE you exec.  I don't see a call to init_debug

Comment: Will edit in the call. The engine is a separate process and executable.